# How can I delete a QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, qsharedpointer

I have written a wrapper around QTextEdit to use it like a QIODevice. I want to be able to use multiple wrapper with the same QTextEdit, so I may use different text color with each wrapper.

To make this wrapper thread-safe I added a QMutex to protect the usage of the QTextEdit. But I was thinking that I must use only one mutex to protect one QTextEdit.

I end up with the following implementation, using a QSharedPointer to protect QTextEdit.

## texteditiodevice.h

```
class TextEditIODevice : public QIODevice
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TextEditIODevice(QTextEdit * qTextEdit, QColor color, QObject * parent);

    virtual ~TextEditIODevice();

protected:
    qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen);

    qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 len);

private:
    /**
     * @brief Pointer to QTextEdit
     */
    QPointer<QTextEdit> textEdit;

    /**
     * @brief Text color
     */
    QColor color;

    /**
     * @brief Shared pointer to QTextEdit associated mutex
     */
    QSharedPointer<QMutex> mutex;

    /**
     * @brief Storage for QTextEdit associated mutexes
     */
    static QMap<QPointer<QTextEdit>, QSharedPointer<QMutex>> mutexes;
};
```

## texteditiodevice.cpp

```
QMap<QPointer<QTextEdit>, QSharedPointer<QMutex>> TextEditIODevice::mutexes;

TextEditIODevice::TextEditIODevice(QTextEdit * qTextEdit, QColor color, QObject * parent) :
    QIODevice(parent),
    textEdit(qTextEdit),
    color(color)
{
    open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

    qRegisterMetaType<QTextCharFormat>("QTextCharFormat");
    qRegisterMetaType<QTextBlock>("QTextBlock");
    qRegisterMetaType<QTextCursor>("QTextCursor");

    if(mutexes.contains(textEdit))
        mutex = mutexes[textEdit];
    else
    {
        mutex = QSharedPointer<QMutex>(new QMutex());
        mutexes.insert(textEdit, mutex);
    }
}

TextEditIODevice::~TextEditIODevice()
{
}

qint64 TextEditIODevice::readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen)
{
    Q_UNUSED(data);
    Q_UNUSED(maxlen);
    return 0;
}



qint64 TextEditIODevice::writeData(const char *data, qint64 len)
{
    if(textEdit)
    {
        mutex->lock();
        const QColor lastColor = textEdit->textColor();
        textEdit->setTextColor(color);
        textEdit->append(QString(data));
        textEdit->setTextColor(lastColor);
        mutex->unlock();
    }

    return len;
}
```

I want to know where I can remove QSharedPointer instance from `mutexes` mapping so the QMutex will be deleted.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You have to rethink your architecture because you cannot do that. [QWidgets are not reentrant and must be used only from the main thread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html). Once you have fixed this you won't need mutexes anymore (only one thread) so the problem will be solved !

Comment: Write data is called in a slot, so it is called from the GUI Thread. But what if two signals are emitted at the same time ?

Comment: If your object is in the main thread and a signal is emitted from another thread then the signal is queued to be processed later by the main thread event loop, so no need to bother with a mutex :). This is however only if you connected your signal using auto (default) or queued connection.
You can look at the section "Signals and Slots Across Threads" in the link I gave above for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the shared pointer is in static `mutexes` map, it will never be deallocated, and the lifetime of `mutexes` is the lifetime of the program.

If you want to actually delete a mutex, you have to remove it from the `mutexes` mapping.

Comment: Or use `QWeakPointer` in `mutexes` map. But I think `QWeakPointer` to null will still stay in map, even after object is deleted, you would have to clear out the null pointers.

Comment: I understand your point. I think i wasn't clear, I want some advice on when I should/can delete the mutex from mutexes mapping.